# Create MS Teams team in C# - more than one owner

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

**Context:**

I am trying to add new team with more than one owner using MS Graph API in C#

**Problem:**

I am getting error message:

> *Adding more than one member is not supported.*

If I add only one member (owner) the team is created. Error occures only for multiple members.
It seems to be impossible it is really not supported but I can't see what am I doing wrong.

**My code:**

```
var owners = model.Owners.Select(x => new AadUserConversationMember
    {
        Roles = new [] { "owner" },
        UserId = x
    });

var newTeam = new Team()
{
    DisplayName = model.DisplayName,
    Description = model.Description,
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["template@odata.bind"] = $"{graph.BaseUrl}/teamsTemplates('standard')",
        ["members"] = owners.ToArray()
    }
};

var team = await graph.Teams.Request().AddAsync(newTeam);
```

***model.Owners*** is a list of teams user ids (`List<string>`)

Comment: If it's not supported, I suggest you stop trying to do it. Add one member to the team, call the method to add the team. After that, call the method to add more members to the team (I'm sure there's a separate method for that).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will probably end with doing it this way but I find it really strange that I cannot do it my way. My guess was that I made a mistake in code and asked the question hoping someone can review it and tell me how to fix it. Additionally, I can create a office 365 group using API and add as many owners as I like. My code also creates the group so I thought it can be done this way. In MS documentation I can't find any information about such restriction.

Comment: You cannot add multiple Owners while creating a Team. You can add only one owner while team creation this is by design. You need to add owners after creating the team.

Comment: Only one owner is only supported in the above scenario. When you see anytime in the Microsoft Document "Not supported" means "it's not going to work, nor they tested to behave to work in other way".

Comment: Not supported means It will not work in other words this is by design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you cannot add multiple owners while creating a team. Only one owner is only supported in the above scenario. When you see anytime in the Microsoft Document "Not supported" means "it's not going to work, nor they tested to behave to work in other way". Hence, it's by design.